# Microsoft SQL Server 2016, Error: 1068 AND Error: 3417 AND Error: 1225 in Windows 10 Pro

Tags: sql-server, windows, connection, database-connection

When try to connect to SQL Server from Microsoft Server Management Studio, I got an error: 1225 occurred; few days ago, it was working fine, but now this error occurs:

[image: Screen Shot Error: 1225 in Microsoft Server Management Studio]

When try to start SQL Server from Services (local) Error 3417 occurred
[image: Screen Shot Error: 3417 in Services (local)]

When try to start to SQL Service Agent through services, then another error #1068 occurs:

[image: Screen Shot Error: 1068 in Services (local)]

Comment: Seems like your Express edition instance is either been removed, or cannot start up ..... see in the "Services" - your "SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)" **must have** a status of "Running" - otherwise that instance isn't up and running and cannot be connected to....

Comment: @marc_s "SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)" is not running, when I try to start it from Services then Error: 3417 occurred....

Answer (score 1):

When I faced similar issue, I did following:

1. In windows `RUN` type **eventvwr.msc** (or go to WindowsEventViewer)
2. Windows Event viewer will be opened.
3. Go to Application Events
4. Try to login to sql server again (it will fail of-course)
5. Now refersh the ApplicationEvents again.
6. You will see the recent error even logged.

This will tell you exact error.

> In my case, my SQL version was expired. And I only knew it from event log.

The only solution I had was to **re-install** sql server.

Answer (score 0):

Who knows the mess you made. Just go to:

```
Start > Microsoft SQL Server 2019 > SQL Server Installation Center > Maintenance > Repair
```

and when it asks to "*browse to the media folder*" I found mine under

```
C:\SQL2019\Developer_ENU
```

the **SETUP:EXE** file is what you are looking for

[image]

follow all the steps of the Repair tool and you will be good to go

Answer (score 0):

Go to Command Prompt as Admin and enter: NET START MSSQLSERVER /T902

More information here: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2018/11/06/sql-server-script-level-upgrade-for-database-master-failed-because-upgrade-step-msdb110_upgrade-sql-encountered-error-926-state-1-severity-25/